# How to create splash or spilling fluid animation from a glass of water

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation, settings

How can I create splash or spilling fluid animation from a glass of water? What is the best way to do it on fluid simulation.?[image: sample simulation I want to achieved]